# How to merge Array Observavble of array in only one Observable of array with RXJS?

Tags: arrays, typescript, rxjs

I want execute x requests in paralel and merge array Observavble of array in only one Observable of array with RXJS?

```
public getMetrics(url: string): Observable<GenericMetric[]> {    
    const ox: Observable<GenericMetric[]>[] = [];
    res.forEach(elem => {
        ox.push(this.http.get<GenericMetric[]>(url));
    });

    return forkJoin(...ox);
}
```

I try:

```
return forkJoin(...ox); // return array of GenericMetric[] but I want all results in GenericMetric[]
```

I looking for how to merge my array of array result in olny one array

```
return forkJoin(ox).pipe(?????);
```

**EDIT:**

I try:

```
return forkJoin(...ox).pipe(tap(d => console.log(d) ));
```

and my result is:

```
[
  [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}],
  [{a:4}, {a:5}]
]
```

but I want :

```
[{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}, {a:5}]
```

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do *"return array of GenericMetric[] but I want all results in GenericMetric[]"*... so it already does what you want?

Comment: `GenericMetric []` is a array. array of `GenericMetric []` is a array of array and not `GenericMetric []` (simple array)

Comment: So you want to turn one emission of `GenericMetric[][]` into multiple emissions of `GenericMetric[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a demo on how you can achieve the desired results. You can use ES6's [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to flatten to array of arrays.

```js
const arr = [
  [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}],
  [{a:4}, {a:5}]
];
const res = [];
arr.map(item => {
  res.push(...item)
})

console.log(res)
```

`forkJoin(ox)` will return you an observable of type `Observable<GenericMetric[]>[]`, which means it is an array of `GenericMetric[]`. There is no way you can simplify that into an array of GenericMetric (`GenericMetric[]`).

However, you can still manipulate the result of `forkJoin(ox)` by making use of pipeable operators such as [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html),

```
forkJoin(ox)
  .pipe( 
    map(res => {
      const result = [];
      res.map(elem => {
        res.push(...elem)
      });
      return result;
    }),
  ).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    // do the rest
  })
```

Comment: @sgrillon it is just a placeholder. I am implying that you can loop through the array of observables.

Comment: I edit my question. I want `[{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}, {a:5}]`

Comment: @sgrillon I have added the code sample on how you can achieve the above array

Comment: Sorry but this is KO (compile KO), I try change `arr.map` by `elem.map` but KO again.

Comment: I try other solution but KO. This sample is online: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kvrhey?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @sgrillon I have edited the code for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b5vdhc?file=src/app/app.component.ts. It should be working now. Use `map` instead of `mergeMap`.

Answer (score 0):

My result is a unic element tab of tab, but if you have multiple tab of tab

```
[
  [
    [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}],
    [{a:4}, {a:5}]
  ],
  [
    [{a:6}, {a:7}, {a:8}],
    [{a:9}, {a:10}]
  ]
]
```

, you can use `switchMap`.

```
public getMetrics(url: string): Observable<GenericMetric[]> {    
    const ox: Observable<GenericMetric[]>[] = [];
    res.forEach(elem => {
        ox.push(this.http.get<GenericMetric[]>(url));
    });

    return forkJoin(ox).pipe(switchMap(allGenericMetrics => {
                              let genericMetrics: GenericMetric[] = [];
                              allGenericMetrics.forEach(metrics => {
                                genericMetrics = genericMetrics.concat(metrics);
                              });
                              return of(genericMetrics);
                             })
                        );
}
```